# Save photo from user with AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with saving photos with Ajax and PHP.

This is my form in HTML

```
<form id="form3">
    <input id="photo3" name="photo" class="form-control" type="file" id="fileInput3" />
</form>
```

And this is my JS

```
data = $("form#form3").serializeArray();
    var file = $("#photo3")[0].files[0];
    data.push({name: "photo", value: file});
    $.ajax({
        url: 'registrace.php',
        data: data,
        complete: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function () {}
    });
```

And this is PHP

```
$output = 'users/'.$namernd.'.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($_GET['photo'],$output);
```

Everything is copied to my database and works, but photo is not saved to my server.

Comment: Is the users directory writable ?

Comment: I have it on XAMPP on my Mac, but i set to folder Write&Read to everyone, so i think it is writable :)

Comment: That js looks incomplete. Try to post as FormData. Some samples https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects FormData with jQuery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Comment: FIle data **never** will be in `GET`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i found solution. Just change to this:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('name', $('#name3'));
    formdata.append('password', $('#password3'));
    formdata.append('city', $('#city3'));
    formdata.append('email', $('#email3'));
    formdata.append('file', $('#photo3')[0].files[0]);
```

And

```
$namernd = uniqid();
$output = 'users/'.$namernd.'.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$output);
```